# Bootbox 'loaded' callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootbox

Does Bootbox.js have a method for invoking a function upon successfully showing a dialog?

I had originally planned to use it to switch a hidden form from elsewhere in the page into the Bootbox, but that can't be done without a callback or callback analogy. Then I devised a way of moving the hidden form in, and in a forehead-smacking cringe-worthy moment I realized that I still needed a callback (or analogy) to now reveal the form (remove the 'hide' class, add the 'in' class).

The documentation does not seem to show a built in property that will allow me to do this (`bootbox.init` shows promise, but I don't fully understand it, it is not documented with examples, and it seems to be global. I use many bootboxes). Is there another way I can do this? Does Bootbox publish an event of some sort?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.init()` is called on a specific dialog, as I showed someone else here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lu1wp3nn/

A simplified example:

```
bootbox
    .alert('Your message')
    .init(function() { 
        /* do something */ 
    });
```

Because bootbox.js is just a wrapper over Bootstrap's modals, you have access to the modal events that Bootstrap defines. You're after `shown.bs.modal` (or `show.bs.modal` if you want to do something just prior to the dialog being shown).

Here's an example, adapted from [the Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

```
bootbox
    .alert('Your message')
    .on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
        // do something...
    })
```

Comment: *forehead smack* I never thought to check the Bootstrap docs. I also got my desired functionality working using .init(). I was using an abstraction of bootbox (in case we swap out another method for showing dialogs) and I opted to pass in a callback. If we use a different method later, it will likely either have a callback or we can shim one in. As it stands, the "callback" is passed into the `init()` as long as it exists and is a function. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To general use:

```
bootbox.alert|confirm({
  "title": lang['EMBED'],
  "message": content
  }).on("shown.bs.modal", function(e) {
   alert()
 });
```